# How to get Ember.js's bindAttr to refresh?

Tags: css, ember.js

I am trying to create "sort by" buttons which change sorting and css-classes when clicked on using Ember.js.

The sorting part and the initial class assignments work, however, the class assignments are not refreshed when I update the dependant properties.

What am I missing?

This is in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sort-option-item">
    <dd {{bindAttr class="IsActive:active IsDesc:reversed"}}
        {{action sortBy on="click"}}><a href="#">{{Name}}</a></dd>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each option in controller.sortOptions}}
        {{view App.SortOptionView controllerBinding="option"}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

An this is in my Javascript:

```
var App = null;

$(function () {

    App = Ember.Application.create();

    // Define Types:

    App.SortOptionCtrl = Ember.Controller.extend({
        Name: null,
        Predicate: null,
        Controller: null,
        IsActive: false,
        IsDesc: false,
        sortBy: function () {
            if (this.Controller != null)
                this.Controller.sortBy(this.Predicate);
        },
        Check: function () {
            this.IsActive = this.Controller != null
                            && this.Controller.isSortedBy(this.Predicate);
            this.IsDesc = this.Controller != null
                          && this.Controller.isSortedDescBy(this.Predicate);
            // adding an alert(this.IsActive); here
            // proves that the function is indeed called and works as expected
        }
    });

    App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

        initialized: false,
        content: [],
        viewContent: [],
        sortProperties: ['Order'],
        sortAscending: true,
        sortOptions: [],

        initialize: function () {

            if (this.initialized == true)
                return;

            this.initialized = true;
            var ctrl = this;

            this.sortOptions.pushObject(App.SortOptionCtrl.create({
                Name: 'Unsorted',
                Predicate: null,
                Controller: ctrl,
            }));
            this.sortOptions.pushObject(App.SortOptionCtrl.create({
                Name: 'By Name',
                Predicate: 'Name',
                Controller: ctrl,
            }));
            this.sortOptions.pushObject(App.SortOptionCtrl.create({
                Name: 'By Date',
                Predicate: 'Date',
                Controller: ctrl,
            }));

            this.sortOptions.forEach(function (opt) { opt.Check(); });
        },

        load: function () {

            this.initialize();
            // ....
        },

        sortBy: function (predicate) {

            var prevPredicate = this.sortProperties[0];

            if (predicate == prevPredicate && predicate != null) {
                this.sortAscending = !(this.sortAscending);
            }
            else {
                this.sortAscending = true;
            }

            this.sortProperties.length = 0;

            if (predicate)
                this.sortProperties.pushObject(predicate);
            else
                this.sortProperties.pushObject('Order');

            this.sortOptions.forEach(function (opt) { opt.Check(); });
        },

        isSortedBy: function (predicate) 
        {
            if (predicate == null)
                predicate = 'Order';

            var activePredicate = this.sortProperties[0];

            if (predicate == activePredicate) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        },

        isSortedDescBy: function (predicate) {

            if (predicate == null)
                predicate = 'Order';

            var activePredicate = this.sortProperties[0];

            if (predicate == activePredicate) {
                if (this.sortAscending)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        },

    });

    App.SortOptionView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'sort-option-item'
    });

    // Create Instances:

    App.productsController = App.ProductsController.create({
    });

    App.productsController.load();

    App.initialize();
});
```

Versions: Ember: 1.0.0-rc.2, handlebars: 1.0.0-rc.3

Comment: I'm a newbie with this and wasn't sure if and how the computed properties would send notifications to the view. I assumed that be inheriting from the controller and setting the properties directly notifications could be sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your views to react to whatever happens in the controller, you should create computed properties (via [`fn(){}.property('dependency')`](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/)). However, in order for computed properties to work properly, you need to use Ember's [`get()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_get) and [`set()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_set) property accessors.

In your code you are doing things like

```
this.IsActive = this.Controller != null && 
                this.Controller.isSortedBy(this.Predicate);
```

When you should be doing something like this:

```
this.set('active',
     this.get('controller') != null &&
     this.get('controller').isSortedBy(this.get('Predicate'))
);
```

You might have noticed that this code is *setting* a value into `active`, but the template is listening to `isActive`. That property has been changed into a computed property:

```
isActive: function() {
    return this.get('active');
}.property('active')
```

It will listen for changes in the `active` property, and whenever that happens, it will cache the new value, and notify all subscriber objects to refresh/update.

Using Ember's `get` and `set` accessors is indicated in order to properly use the observables that make this chain of events possible.

I have modified your sample applying `get` and `set` where appropriate.
You can see it in this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/fRMYu/**

Comment: So using this.get('propertyName') causes Ember to enlist subscribe to change notifications?

Comment: A [`Computed Property`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html), with the `property` decorator, will cache the returning value of the function and act somewhat like an observer. All parts of the application subscribing to this observer (a call to that property in your Handlebars template, for instance) will be notified when that value changes, and will execute their own workflow to react to the value change.

Answer (score 0):

After Joe's help, more reading of Ember's manual and clean up of my code, I got to this sorter solution:

Sort option controller:

```
App.SortOptionCtrl = Em.Controller.extend({
    Name: null,
    Predicate: null,

    _isActive: false,
    isActive: function () {
        return this.get('_isActive');
    }.property('_isActive'),

    _isDesc: false,
    isDesc: function () {
        return this.get('_isDesc');
    }.property('_isDesc'),

    controller: null,

    updateState: function () {
        if (!this.Predicate) {
            this.set('_isActive', (this.get('controller')
                .get('activePredicate') == null));
            this.set('_isDesc', false);
        }
        else {
            this.set('_isActive', (this.get('controller')
                .get('activePredicate') == this.Predicate));
            this.set('_isDesc', (this.get('_isActive')
                && !this.get('controller').get('sortAscending')));
        }
    }.observes('controller.activePredicate', 'controller.sortAscending'),

    sortBy: function () {
        if (this.get('controller') != null) {
            this.get('controller').sortBy(this.Predicate);
        }
    },
});
```

Products controller:

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    content: [],
    viewContent: [],
    activePredicate: null,
    sortProperties: ['Order'],
    sortAscending: true,
    sortOptions: [],

    filter: function (obj) {
        return true;
    },

    init: function () {

        this._super();

        var ctrl = this;

        this.sortOptions.pushObject(App.SortOptionCtrl.create({
            Name: 'Unsorted',
            Predicate: null,
            controller: ctrl,
        }));
        this.sortOptions.pushObject(App.SortOptionCtrl.create({
            Name: 'By Name',
            Predicate: 'Name',
            controller: ctrl,
        }));
        this.sortOptions.pushObject(App.SortOptionCtrl.create({
            Name: 'By Date',
            Predicate: 'Date',
            controller: ctrl,
        }));

        this.sortOptions.forEach(function (opt) {
            opt.updateState();
        });
    },

    sortBy: function (predicate) {

        var prevPredicate = this.sortProperties[0];

        if (predicate == prevPredicate && predicate != null) {
            this.set('sortAscending', !(this.get('sortAscending')));
        }
        else {
            this.set('sortAscending', true);
        }

        this.set('activePredicate', predicate);
        this.set('sortProperties.length', 0);

        if (predicate)
            this.get('sortProperties').pushObject(predicate);
        else
            this.get('sortProperties').pushObject('Order');
    },

});
```